# How to use Sumif in Google sheets with many ranges?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I have a spreadsheet that has summary information for individuals by month, and I want to sum the information for all participants, but I need to break it down conditionally by year. The big issue is that the information is not all stacked on top of each other in two columns(month & info), they are broken up by person with titles in between, so I have to use multiple ranges.

For example, my code now looks something like this:

=sumif([A2:A6,A9:A17,A19:A25], "<13", [D2:D6,D9:D17,D19:D25])

Except I am doing this with hundreds of ranges. The brackets are not working and I am not sure how to use an Array. I would really appreciate someones help on this, as I have been racking my brain for awhile now.

Comment: You can't use multiple ranges like that - what sort of values are in A7:A8 and D7:D8? Is there any consistent text/values in the excluded rows that can be used as an additional criterion?

Comment: Thank you for your response! The values are numerical in both ranges, but A7:A8 and D7:D8 are character. They are consistent text all the way through the spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=sumif(A:A,"<13",D:D)
```

or, if there are values in row26 or below and in row1 to be excluded:

```
=sumif(A2:A25,"<13",D2:D25)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, the following would work:

```
=sum(filter(D2:D25,ISNUMBER(A2:A25),A2:A25 >13))
```

The idea:

1. Filter for rows that are numeric (you said the content in between are titles!?) and meet your requirement (>13).
2. Sum it up! (By the right column)